# What does PDS stand for?

Tags: investing, terminology

I am looking at a funds [fact sheet](https://www.allangray.co.za/globalassets/documents-repository/fund/factsheet/Allan%20Gray%20Australia%20Equity%20Fund%20(AUD)/Latest/Allan%20Gray%20Australia%20Equity%20Fund%20(AUD)%20Latest.pdf). The fact sheet contains the following warning

> Past performance is not a reliable indicator of future results. You
>   should consider the PDS before making any investment decision.

In this context, what does PDS stand for? I searched on the net and found some likely candidates; "Product Disclosure Statement" and "Product Data Sheet".

My guess would be that it stands for "Product Disclosure Statement". Is my guess correct or is it something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the context of Australian funds, this is the [Product Disclosure Statement](https://download.asic.gov.au/media/1240931/rg168-published-28-october-2011.pdf) mandated by the Australian Securities & Investments Commission.